# How to show content only to user that created it?

Tags: python, django

I have program like todo list. And I need to filter db to show only content that user created

I have code like this:

```
name = Gift.objects.filter(author=request.user)
```

But it show error

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'author' into field. Choices are: gift_name, id, person_name, user, user_id
```

Comment: try this:
if user doesnt work, replace it with user_id
```name = Gift.objects.filter(user=request.user)```

Comment: Great, Please Accept my answer here @frod wii
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74914450/5235168

Comment: ok, i need to wait 7 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
Also it is mentioned in the warning to use which attriubutes as a hint.
since author is not preset you have to use user

```
name = Gift.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```